# How to extract some specific rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a unmpy array and want to extract some rows of the array. My array has three columns which are x, y and z coordinates:

```
sr_y=np.array([[10., 1., 8.], [20., 1., 8.1], [30., 1., 7.9], [10., 2., 8.],\
              [20., 2., 7.9], [30., 2., 8.], [10., 1., 1.9], [20., 1., 2.],\
              [10., 2., 2.1], [20., 2., 2.2], [30., 2., 1.8]])
```

The array is sorted one. The rows with the same values in their second column are such kind of subset. First three rows of `sr_y` have the same value in their second column, so I want the last row (`[30., 1., 7.9]`). Then, again rows 4, 5 and 6 make the next subset and I want the last row (the 6th). Then, from row 6 to 7, the third column changes a lot (from `8` to `1.9`). From here to end, I want to extract the first row of each subset. Rows 7 and 8 are a subset and I want row 7. From rows 9, 10 and 11, I want the first one (9th row). Briefly speaking, I want to following array:

```
np.array([[30., 1., 7.9], [30., 2., 8.], [10., 1., 1.9], [10., 2., 2.1]])
```

I tried the following code but it did not give me what I want:

```
exported_data=np.array([])
for i in range (len(sr_y)-1):
    if sr_y[i,1] != sr_y[i+1,1] or sr_y[i-1,2]>int (sr_y[i,2]+4):
        aa=sr_y[i]
        exported_data=np.append (exported_data,aa)
exported_data=exported_data.reshape(-1,3)
```

In fact, it can not modify role of export after the big change of the third column. After that big change, I want to export the first row of each subset. In advance, Thanks for any help. I do appreciate any contribution.

Comment: What's your criterium for choosing the first or last element for each subset?

Comment: Dear @Ivan, subsets are sorted by the first column. first one has the lowest value and last one has the highest.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the third row of your resulting array is `[10. ,  1. ,  1.9]` and not `[20. ,  1. ,  2. ]` (same for the fourth one where it's `[10. ,  2. ,  2.1]` and not `[30. ,  2. ,  1.8]`?

Comment: Because a big change occured in the third column of my data. the third column in 6th row is 8 and in 7th row is 1.9. after this change, I want to extract the first row of each subset. Before the big change, I want the last row of each subset, after that I want the last row. Thanks for devoting time to my issue.

Comment: Ok, and is there only one big change? Or can there be multiple?

Comment: There are changes but thats the biggest one I can say. But for sure I have minor changes. I think the threshold I regarded (`sr_y[i,2]+4`) is not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to indicate if the *big step* has already occured or not.

```
delta = 4
before = True
for i in range(sr_y.shape[0]-1):
    if before and sr_y[i][0] > sr_y[i+1][0]:
        print('(last)', sr_y[i])
    if sr_y[i][2] > sr_y[i+1][2] + delta:
        before = False
    if not before and sr_y[i][0] > sr_y[i+1][0]:
        print('(first)', sr_y[i+1])
```

The first condition will catch last values (`>` check) for all subsets before the *big step* (`before`). The second condition handles the flag switch. While the third and last condition catches first values (`>` check) for all subsets after the *big step* (`not before`).

**Note:** Replace the `print()` calls with the `list.append()` accordingly. It's important that the conditions remain in this order. Since on the iteration where the *big set* occurs, it will have to catch both the last value for the previous subset and the first value from the following.